# Trying to decrypt password win32crypt.CryptUnprotectedData

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, encryption, passwords

I've written a script to decrypt old passwords and accounts that I can't access because I can't access my old email (again because I can't remember the passwords haha).

```
import os
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
import sys

try:
    path = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    for w in os.walk(os.getenv('USERPROFILE')):
        if 'Chrome' in w[1]:
            path = str(w[0]) + '/Chrome/User Data/Default/Login Data'
try:
    print ('[+] Opening ' + path)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except Exception as e:
    print ('[-] %s' % (e)) 
    sys.exit(1)

# Get the results
try:
    cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
except Exception as e:
    print ('[-] %s' % (e))
    sys.exit(1)

data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Everything is fine up to here.

```
for result in data:
    try:
        password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2], None)

    except Exception as e:
        print('[-] %s' % (e))
        pass

    if password:
        print("[+] URL: {} Username: {} Password: {}".format(result[0], result[1], password))
    else: print("Unable to extract data")
```

I get this error: (-2146893813, 'CryptProtectData', 'Key not valid for use in specified state.')

Thanks to gilliduck for pointing out my typo!

Comment: Right so if you read the comment below, I've changed it so that it's no longer CryptUnprotectedData, but rather CryptUnprotectData. However, there's still the issue about the 'Key not Valid for use in specified state.'

Comment: OK, then unaccept the answer as it doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's

```
CryptUnprotectData
```

not

```
CryptUnprotectEDData
```

Comment: Thank you! I've edited that and now have a new error :/